# Show/hide divs based on real date excluding year

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 7/8 divs that I need to hide when they're not relevant.  I have been working on this for a week and and am stumped. 
psudocode:

```
<script> 
 x= get date
 if (date  <= showbefore & >= showafter){show div}
<html>
<div 1 showbefore = a showafter = b> !-- advert for valentines
<div 1 showbefore = a showafter = c> !-- advert for mothers day
<div 1 showbefore = d showafter = f> !-- advert for easter sunday
<div 1 showbefore = h showafter = x> !-- advert for christmas.
```

have been advised a few ways to do this but not the way it should behave. I need it to behave the same way in 2016,2017 etc.

feel free to advise a better way to do this with any library or premade script even.

Thanks

Comment: Are you stumped on showing and hiding the divs or on the date logic to decide when to show or hide?

Comment: I think I  can use CSS to hide the dives and an if statement that will change the display.none to display.block? My primary issue with this question is the data logic.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZQyLr

### HTML

```
<!-- the dates are in "MM-DD" format; always 5 characters altogether -->
<div data-visible-from="01-09" data-visible-to="02-15">Hi!</div>
<div data-visible-from="02-10" data-visible-to="03-15">Hi too!</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
// The current month and year, sliced from the full ISO8601 date string,
// i.e. "02-16" from "2016-02-16T......"
var md = (new Date()).toISOString().substring(5, 10);
// Find all elements with the visible-from or visible-to attributes,
// turn them into an array with [].slice.call and then iterate over them
// with the regular array forEach...
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-visible-from],[data-visible-to]")).forEach(function(el) {
  // Nab the visible-from date, or if it's not available, then the smallest
  // possible date per year (1 Jan)
  var from = el.dataset.visibleFrom || "01-01";
  // Ditto, with 31 Dec being the fallback.
  var to = el.dataset.visibleTo || "12-31";
  // Then simply set the element's `display` to none if today's not the day.
  el.style.display = (from <= md && md <= to ? "" : "none");
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! I can't make any sense of what you did because I'm totally new to this but I copied your code pen JS into a function that starts on body page load and it seems to be working! Thanks a bunch :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
<html><body>

<div style="display:none" showbefore = a showafter = b>advert for valentines</div>
<div  style="display:none" showbefore = a showafter = c>advert for mothers day</div>
<div style="display:none" showbefore = d showafter = f>advert for easter sunday</div>
<div style="display:none" showbefore = h showafter = x>advert for christmas. </div>

<script>
  var date = new Date(),
  day = date.getDate(),
  month = date.getMonth();

  if (day == 14 && month ==2) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.display = "block";
  }
  else if () {
    //...
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```